# Having trouble removing and applying event handler on window resize. (Works in FireFox not in Chrome)

Tags: jquery

I want a button that shows or hides a `div`, but when I resize the browser and trigger a media query I want to disable the button, enabling it again when resizing to the previous media query.

I'm using media queries with `body:after {content:'tablet'; display:none;}`, `body:after {content:'laptop'; display:none;}` and it works fine.

I'm using jQuery `.on();` and `.off();` to add/remove an event handler on window resize. The problem I'm having is that the event handler is getting added but it's toggling off straight away when I click it, going back to the 'tablet` viewport size.

How do I make it so that when I resize to the "laptop" size I remove the handler, but when I resize to "tablet" again I add the event handler.

**jQuery**

```
function chooseMenu() {
    $('#sidebarWrapper').css('position', 'absolute').stop(true, true).toggle('showOrHide');
} // button function

if (size != currentSize) {
    if (size == 'tablet') {
        $('.menuButton').on('click', chooseMenu);
        $('#sidebarWrapper').css('display', 'none');
        currentSize = 'tablet';
    }
    if (size == 'laptop') {
        $('.menuButton').off();
        $('#sidebarWrapper').css('position', 'static');
        $('#sidebarWrapper').css('display', 'block');
        currentSize = 'laptop';
    }
} //if size
```

I'm assuming there's something wrong with my on/off or the toggle logic which I must be missing. If this isn't the case and you need to see more just ask or just check out the live site. It's the menu button on the grey strip on the left hand side. http://lartmagazine.co.uk/. (sorry for the link I just don't know how to show this in a fiddle).

Err.. Upon just checking my link I noticed that it works in FireFox but not in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to throttle my functions when I resized the window, I installed underscore.js and used this:

```
$(window).resize(_.debounce(function(){

},100));
```

I actually had this installed before but forgot about it playing around with other stuff...